# Stop the n+1 in an eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Currently, when I'm retrieving the `messages`, it is presenting the n+1 issue:

```
select * from `messages` where `messages`.`alert_id` = '21'
```

This sometimes is replicated over 100+ times!

Controller function:

```
public function getAdminIndex() {
    $company = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
               ->companies()
               ->with('users.alerts.location')
               ->first();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.admin.index', 
                             array('company' => $company));
}
```

User Model:

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Company')->withTimestamps();
}

public function credits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Usage');
}

public function deletedAlerts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Alert')->onlyTrashed();
}

public function alerts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Alert');
}
```

Alert Model:

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Location');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Message');
}
```

Message Model:

```
public function alert()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Alert');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

If I use the following line of code, I can see the MYSQL is correct, but it then can't find the location method:

```
->companies()
->with('users.alerts.messages.location')
->first();
```

select * from messages where messages.alert_id in ('21', '42')

I think it maybe a relationship issue, but I'm unsure of how to resolve it. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Show the code causing n+1 issue, in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to load 2 relations on the `Alert` model (guessing without view code, but 99% sure):

```
public function getAdminIndex() {
$company = // User::find(Auth::user()->id)
           Auth::user()  // better approach as in @ollieread's comment
           ->companies()
           ->with('users.alerts.location', 'users.alerts.messages')
           ->first();
$this->layout->content = View::make('agents.admin.index', 
                         array('company' => $company));
}
```

This will execute only 1 additional query for the `messages` relation, because `users.alerts` are already loaded.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you, Deczo! You should update Laravel's documentation ;)

Comment: You don't actually need to refer to the relationship using `user` either, so `->with('alerts.location', 'alerts.messages')` would suffice. I would also suggest telling it to load `alert`, just so it makes sense.

Comment: @ollieread, that's incorrect since it's relation on the Company model through m-m users (of the currently logged in user, yes)

Comment: Relationships shouldn't be called in the way, nor should a user be called using `Auth::user()->id`. It should be `Auth::user()->companies()->with(..)` otherwise there's an entirely pointless db call in there.